# How to read 2D arrays in C?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I'm learning about 2D arrays in C and I'm a bit confused. I have the following program which reads a 2D arrays and adds its values in another array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {        
    int arr[4][5] = {{1,2,3,4,5},
                     {3,1,1,5,2},
                     {4,1,4,1,5},
                     {2,5,3,3,4}};
    int many[4];
    int i;

    for (i=0;i<4;i++) {
        many[i] = arr[i][i] + arr[i][i];
        printf("%d\n", many[i]);
    }
```

The output of this program is:

```
2
2
8
6
```

But I think it should be `3, 3, 9, 7` because the for loop starts at 1 and the first column and row gets 1 and second column and row get 2 because there is already 1 which means 1+1 = 2 and 2 + 1 = 3, for second number it is same idea.
For the third number I got 9 because we get 4 from row 2 column 2. 4 + 4 + 1 = 9 and for last number I got 7 because last row has 3 in row 3 column 3.

Comment: I don't know where you think you should be getting the extra `1` from. You're iterating diagonally through the arrays. `arr[0][0]` is the top left, so it's `1+1=2`. Then `arr[1][1]` is the second element of the second array, so it's `1+1=2`. Then `arr[2][2]` is the third element of the third array, so it's `4+4=3`. Then `3+3=6`. That's why you're getting the output you're getting.

Comment: What is many supposed to contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **output** you get is absolutely right for this loop.

```
  for (i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    many[i] = arr[i][i] + arr[i][i];
    printf("%d\n", many[i]);
}
```

You can easily get to know it by **tracing**.

---

**so let's trace it...**

**during i=0**

`arr[0][0]` denotes *1st element* ***(as indices start from 0)*** of *1st array* which is **1**

```
many[0] = arr[0][0]+arr[0][0] // 1+1=2
```

**during i=1**

arr[1][1] denotes *2nd element* of *2nd array* which is also **1**

```
many[0] = arr[1][1]+arr[1][1] // 1+1=2
```

**during i=2**

arr[2][2] denotes *3rd element* of *3rd array* which is **4**

```
many[2] = arr[2][2]+arr[2][2] // 4+4=8
```

**during i=3**

arr[3][3] denotes *4th element* of *4th array* which is **3**

```
many[3] = arr[3][3]+arr[3][3] // 3+3=6
```

---

Therefore,The output of this program is:

```
2
2
8
6
```

> Note: arr[m][n] denotes (n+1)th element of (m+1)th array

Comment: why are you not adding the [i+1], I mean you said first element of the many array is 2 1+1=2, but why you did not add the 1 that was there before?

Comment: **but why you did not add the 1 that was there before?** which 1 are you speaking about?? @Batool

Comment: I am asking about the entire output. i = j[i][i] + j[i][i+1]; we have i+1 in the second j, so should we have i which is 1 for the first repeat add to 1 in that number becomes 2 and 3 in total I mean j[1] + j[2] = 3

Comment: man once look at your code it doesn't have `arr[i][i]+arr[i][i+1]` instead it has `arr[i][i]+arr[i][i]` @Batool

Comment: oh sorry, that was a typing mistake. There should have been [i+1], but I thought I had it there. Sorry

Comment: but then too you'll end up with different output not 3,3,9,7 you'll get 3,2,5,7

Comment: @Batool I know you've typed in wrong question but I think this answers your question.. So please mark it as answer for future users as it would be helpful for them

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 loops to iterate through your 2D array

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
        int arr[4][5] = {{1,2,3,4,5},
                         {3,1,1,5,2},
                         {4,1,4,1,5},
                         {2,5,3,3,4}};
        int many[4];
        int i;
        int j;
        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            many[i] = 0;
            for(j=0;j<5;j++)
            {
                many[i] += arr[i][j];
            }
            printf("%d\n", many[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It wasn't me, but you should read the Question =>>  "I have the following program `which reads a 2D arrays and adds its values in another array.`"

Comment: and the question is not about how to do it but, about the output and why is it so

Comment: @ch3rub7 I read it as the OP was confused about how to iterate over the loop, I like your answer though :) Ive edited mine hope that helps someone

Comment: @RyanFitzpatrick OP needs the output to be: `3, 3, 9, 7` and not `15 12 15 17`

Comment: @Michi Does the OP need it to be 3,3,9,7? Or do they think that's the correct output? Did they ever specify what many is supposed to contain?

Comment: @RyanFitzpatrick OP said that he expected that output to be `3, 3, 9, 7`, why should be that output I have no ideas. He doesn't explain too much.

Comment: @Michi I've commented on the question asking the OP to explain, if they respond i'll update my answer :)